# How to clear a pipe buffer

Tags: linux, pipe, buffer

I want to clear the data in a pipe buffer right before I close the write end, so that the read end will receive EOF signal immediately. Is it possible?

Comment: similar post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441290/is-there-an-easy-way-of-clearing-a-pipe-in-c

Comment: Why would you need to do this? The only way is to read from the pipe. Maybe you can tell us about what you're trying to achieve.